# Are Essbase questions on-topic / within scope on dba.SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Essbase is Oracle's BI OLAP product (formerly from Hyperion, formerly Arbor).  Is this an appropriate site for questions about Essbase (and other OLAP products for that matter)?  Or are we sticking more to the relational side of things here?

Answer (score 7):

I am almost 100% certain that this will be welcome. If it becomes too much of "how do I format" or "how do I prettify" then we'll nudge people in a better direction, but for being a BI OLAP product, it's almost certainly welcome here. Go ahead and put up your questions, that would be a much better way to tell.

Comment: Great, thanks!  The questions I had in mind are definitely from the administrative / dba perspective.  How much traffic they get?  Well, I guess we'll see.

Answer (score 3):

OLAP questions are certainly on-topic here.  We've got quite a bit of material about SSAS.  Essbase is well on-topic, especially now we've rolled in the Area 51 Business Intelligence proposal.